# No results found to publish. Unit tests in Azure DevOps build

Tags: .net, unit-testing, azure-devops, code-coverage

I tried to configure my build to run the unit tests of the project but I should be doing something wrong.

The structure of my project is something like this (using .NET Framework 4.6.1):

```
Solution 'Project.Testing'
    Project1.XXXX
    Project1.XXXX.Test
    Project2.XXXX
    Project2.XXXX.Test
```

[image: Visual Studio Test Build Configuration]

[image: Visual Studio Test Build Configuration 2]

But I'm getting this report:

[image: Test Assemblies report]

Any idea of what's happening? Thanks in advance!

Comment: its looking for dll, not for csproj files?

Comment: Do you have an appropriate test adapter NuGet package installed in your test projects?

Comment: @4c74356b41 yep, but I configured the default options, I just actiivated the "Enable Code Coverage" option.

Comment: @DanielMann I have installed MSTest.TestAdapter and MSTest.TestFramework from nuget package. Should be another one?